# Efficient approach to minimally pad a tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to pad a tensor of some shape such that the total memory used by the tensor is always a multiple of 512 E.g. Tensor shape 16x1x1x4 of type SI32 (Multiply by 4 to get total size)

```
The total elements are 16x4x1x1 = 64
Total Memory required 64x**4** = 256 (Not multiple of 512)
Padded shape would be 32x1x1x4 = 512
```

The below logic works for the basic shape but breaks with a shape e.g. `16x51x1x4 SI32` or something random say `80x240x1x1 U8`. To overcome it I wrote a brute force but it pads the tensor non optimally.

The padding logic goes like below

```
from functools import reduce

DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER = 2 # This would change at runtime with different type e.g. 8 with U8 16 with F16 32 with SI32

ALIGNMENT = 512 #Always Constant
CHAR_BIT = 8    # Always Const for given fixed Arch

def approachOne(tensor):
    totalElements = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), tensor)
    totalMemory = totalElements * DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER
    
    divisor = tensor[1] * tensor[2] * tensor[3]
    tempDimToPad = totalElements/divisor
    orgDimToPad = totalElements/divisor
    while (True):
        if ((tempDimToPad * divisor * DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER) % ALIGNMENT == 0):
            return int(tempDimToPad - orgDimToPad)
        tempDimToPad = tempDimToPad + 1;
    
def getPadding(tensor):
    totalElements = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), tensor)
    totalMemory = totalElements * DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER
    newSize = totalMemory + (ALIGNMENT - (totalMemory % ALIGNMENT))
    newTotalElements = (newSize * CHAR_BIT) / (CHAR_BIT * DATA_TYPE_MULTIPLYER)
    
    # Always pad 1st DIM as it represents total number of channels
    paddingValue = tensor[0] 
    padding =  int(((newTotalElements * paddingValue) / totalElements) - paddingValue)
    return padding
    
tensor = [11, 7, 3, 5]
print(getPadding(tensor))
print(approachOne(tensor))
```

tensorflow package may help here but I'm originally coding in C++ so just posting in python with a minimal working example Any improvement feedback is appreciated

**Approach 1** the brute force approach is to keep on incrementing the number of channels by 1 and check if the totalMemory is multiple of `512`. The brute force approach works but doesn't give the minimal padding and bloats the tensor

Comment: What do you mean by "it pads the tensor non optimally"? How is optimal padding defined?

Comment: Why is this being done? If it's for performance, do you have evidence that it helps?

Comment: The padding itself doesn't help but it's a prerequisite for a feature that improves the perf